# Blank Field in Mysql After Uploading Data

Tags: php, android, mysql

I was uploading data from my android application to a PHP file then inserting it to Mysql database, the problem i am having that i buy a new hosting plan and when i configured everything in the new hosting, i try to upload data from the application it shows only blank fields in the table, i am sure that there's no problem in the PHP or the android code, cause it was working fine and great with the old hosting.. i tried to change the encoding but same issue.

Here's the PHP file:

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("HOST","USER","PASS");
if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not Connect:'. mysql_error());
    }
mysql_select_db("TABLE",$con);


mysql_query ("INSERT INTO table (rep_desc,dateT) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['report_Desc']."','".$_REQUEST['Date_Time']."')");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: it may be case sensitive. check your table name .. database and fields.

Comment: Also check if any new row actually get inserted?

Comment: @MittulChauhan, i checked and all are the same!

Comment: @ZeeshanElahi, yes row is inserted but it's empty!, only the auto incremented column is increased!

Comment: echo your this query `"INSERT INTO table (rep_desc,dateT) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['report_Desc']."','".$_REQUEST['Date_Time']."'";`

and try to insert manually in database table and check what happens.

Comment: do this `mysql_select_db("TABLE",$con) or die(mysql_error());` instead of `mysql_select_db("TABLE",$con);`

Comment: @Izzo32 check these things .. should work

Comment: @MittulChauhan, i tried to insert manually it works

Comment: @Izzo32  ok did you try this ?      $result = mysql_query('your query');
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

Comment: Also try **print_r($_REQUEST]**. Just to check if proper data is coming in $_REQUEST array.

Comment: @Izzo32 let us know if you find any solution or not

Comment: @MittulChauhan, tried what you posted still blank field

Comment: @ZeeshanElahi, yes it's a proper data that receives to the php file

Comment: @Izzo32 do one thing . create new table (make sure case sensitiveness ) with the maximum 2 fields (id [auto increment], name [varchar]) and run php code and try to insert in a static way .. and check if this works or not. let me know

Comment: @MittulChauhan, i did that and same issue happens an empty field, but when i try to manually insert from the PHP files it inserts !

Comment: @Izzo32   try this and tell me the error plz 

mysql_query ("INSERT INTO table (rep_desc,dateT) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['report_Desc']."','".$_REQUEST['Date_Time']."')"); or die(mysql_error());

Comment: @MittulChauhan, i've tried to use the exactly same php file in the old hosting and i point it to the database in the new hosting and it worked fine, fields are filled!!, That's weird

Comment: @Izzo32 alternatively , you can talk to your hosting provider about this issue and tell them in which situation you are in. Probably they would say something .

Answer (score 1):

1. If there is any **auto_increment** column in table. Better check if its **auto_increment** flag not got uncheck.
2. Please also check length of database fields and data that you actually trying to insert.
3. Name of all request variables, columns, tables should be in proper case if it is a UNIX system.

Comment: I do have auto_increment column, but what's that flag you're talkin about?

Comment: Owh, sorry yea it's checked.

Comment: Checked them all, and all are okai

Answer (score 0):

get all the tables by something like this query ...

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);


if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "Table: {$row[0]}\n";
}
```

Comment: by checking this.. you will atleast come to know that you are able to load your tables ..